# SoundManager / Jquery : Get SoundID sID

Tags: jquery, html, regex, soundmanager2

So I am trying to access a jquery soundmanager variable from one script (wpaudio.js – from the wp-audio plugin) inside of another (init.js – my own javascript). I am creating an alternate pause/play button higher up on the page and need to resume the current soundID, which is contained as part of a class name in the DOM.

Here is the code that creates that class name in wpaudio.js:

```
function wpaButtonCheck() {
if (!this.playState || this.paused)
    jQuery('#' + this.sID + '_play').attr('src', wpa_url + '/wpa_play.png');
else
    jQuery('#' + this.sID + '_play').attr('src', wpa_url + '/wpa_pause.png');
```

}

Here is the output:

```
<img src="http://24.232.185.173/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wpaudio-mp3-player/wpa_play.png" class="wpa_play" id="wpa0_play">
```

where wpa0 would be the sID of the sound I need.

My current script in init.js is:

```
    $('.mixesSidebar #currentSong .playBtn').toggle(function() {
        soundManager.pauseAll();
        $(this).addClass('paused');
    }, function() {
        soundManager.resumeAll();
        $(this).removeClass('paused');
    });
```

I need to change resumeAll to "resume(this.sID)", but I need to somehow store the sID onclick and call it in the above function.

Alternately, I think a regular expression that could get the class name of the current play button and either parse the string up to the "_play" or use a trim function to get rid of "_play"– but I'm not sure how to do this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was the following. Took out the string "+_play" in lines 33, 35, and 54 in wpaudio.js. Subsequently, the play button  element for each mp3 has an ID attribute equal to it's soundmanager id. So I just created the following variable in my own .js:

```
$('.mixPlayCell a').click( function() {
     var songsId = $(this).find('img').attr('id');
});
```

When you click on the mp3 , this stores the sID in the variable songsId

I'd still like to know how to actually directly retrieve the sID without such a work-around...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method that could store some extra data related to an element, so you don't have to parse class name, just add that sID to an img.